# Cannot log-in to google play games service when app is installed

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-signin

I made google-api-client with this code

```
GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)                    
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
                .addApi(Games.API)                  
                .build();
```

and connect to service with this code

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
```

connection is successful but I can't get serverauthcode because
mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API) returns false
without any warning or error

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

     if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API)) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
               new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {

                       // In this case, we are sure the result is a success.
                       GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();                          
                       mAccountAuthCode = signInAccount.getServerAuthCode();    

                       Player player = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);
                       mAccountId = player.getPlayerId();
                       Log.i(MYTAG, "login success");           


                   }
               }
        );
    } 
    else
    {           
        Log.i(MYTAG, "connected but no Games.API Why!");            
    }
```

Strangely if I just disconnect and reconnect ,
mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API) return true and all things are fine.

Also if I just relaunch app 
mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API) return true and all things are fine.

I wonder why I cannot connect google-play-games-service api with first try.

I'm using latest google play service sdk(10.2.4)

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Try disabling Instant Run. Go to Settings and uncheck Enable instant run and then launch the app.

Comment: Sallu // is Instant Run Android Studio feature? I'm using gradle directly to build my apk and deploy with adb at console.

Comment: Yes it is. Go to File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run->Uncheck First Checkbox

Comment: Sallu // I have no Android Studio, so I'm not using Instant Run feature.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/yoK46I2CTVw). Try restarting your device. If that doesn't help, then clear the cache. If issues persist, you can also try uninstalling and reinstalling Play Store app updates.

For ***mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API) returns false***, you may check this link: [GoogleApiClient.isConnected() return always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966198/googleapiclient-isconnected-return-always-false)

> You need to add a couple callback listeners to the Builder (or GoogleApiClient).  What's most likely happening is that the login is failing because you don't have permissions yet.  You need to handle that failure so that the user can authorize your app.
>
> More reading: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/14/for-developers-google-play-services-4-2-includes-new-client-api-model-consolidates-connections-under-one-object/

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() returns true. only mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API) returns false. and onConnectionFailedListener is never called.